# Referencing and counting columns belonging to hierarchy

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I would like to be able to reference an upper hierarchy column, and to be able to count the number of columns and list the names of the columns it has.

This is the dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']), np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=arrays)
```

And this is the output:

```
        bar                 baz                 foo                 qux
        one       two       one       two       one       two       one       two
A  0.050343 -0.525009  0.126593 -0.332575 -1.233224  0.415279  1.097570  0.096461
B  2.371400 -0.184967 -0.470547  2.203325 -0.914778  0.392034  0.398723  1.047543
C  0.977506  1.606047 -0.993077 -0.804615  0.654538 -0.099860  0.679309 -1.313231
```

I'm trying to understand how to find the number of columns belonging to a certain hierarchy (for instance the number of columns for `bar`.

My attemps don't seem to work because I'm expecing 2 as the output for the `print(len())` function and `[one, two]` as output for the `print()` function.

Attempt 1:

```
print(len(df.columns))
print(df.columns)
8
MultiIndex([('bar', 'one'),
            ('bar', 'two'),
            ('baz', 'one'),
            ('baz', 'two'),
            ('foo', 'one'),
            ('foo', 'two'),
            ('qux', 'one'),
            ('qux', 'two')],
           )
```

Attempt 2:

```
print(len(df.columns[1]))
print(df.columns[1])
2
('bar', 'two')
```

Attempt 3:

```
print(len(df.columns['bar'])
print(df.columns['bar'])
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

The desired output would be:

```
2
['one','two']
```

Comment: Do you need unique first level columns? Then `list(set(df.columns.get_level_values(1)))`

Comment: This works perfect, I didn't know about the `get_level_values` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about plain selection?:

```
>>> df['bar']
        one       two
A -0.671483  0.349299
B  0.475603  0.576552
C -0.141044 -1.063308
>>> df['bar'].shape
(3, 2)
>>> df['bar'].columns
Index(['one', 'two'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Ahh yes! It works, I think I was so winded up in the columns method I should reference the index first and then apply the column method. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need unique first level columns, use,

```
list(set(df.columns.get_level_values(1)))
```